# Trouble retrieving an attribute in SQL query

Tags: sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have the following relational schema.

**EMPLOYEE**(Fname, Lname, *Ssn*, Salary, Dno)

**DEPARTMENT**(Dname, *Dnumber*, Mgr_ssn)

For each department, I would like to retrieve the department number, manager first name and the departments average salary.

Below is my attempt. I get the department number and average salary but I can't understand how to retrieve the department manager name without filtering rows which would change the value of the average salary.

```
SELECT D.Dnumber, AVG(E.Salary)
FROM EMPLOYEE E JOIN DEPARTMENT D ON E.Dno = D.Dnumber
GROUP BY D.Dnumber
```

How do I retrieve the manager first name within this query?

Comment: Get manager ids & averages per department. Then join to get names. This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask] [help] When you do post a code question: [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the link to the manager is through the SSN.  To me, it is a bad idea to use PII (personally identifiable information) for such a purpose.

In any case, you need *two* joins to get the first name, so you are half-way there:

```
select d.dnumber, avg(e.salary), em.fname
from employee e join
     department d
     on e.dno = d.dnumber left join
     employee em
     on e.ssn = em.mgr_ssn
group by d.dnumber, em.fname;
```